# Grease/tamper monkey script to look for specific HTML in page and alert

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I would like a grease/tamper monkey script, that when I visit a page, it looks for the following HTML on the page, and if it is present alert.

```
<p>
  <script 
    type='text/javascript' 
    src='https://site_im_visiting.com/?a(6 hex characters)=(numbers)'>
  </script>
</p>
```

Additionally, I would like to look inside an array (of about 4k sites), to see if the site is in the array.

Comment: You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out on my own, but instead of looking for the HTML, looked for the URL of the src of the script block

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script")
var expression = /.*\/\?a[a-f0-9]{6}\=\d+?/gi;
const domains =["something.com","google.com"]
for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; ++i) {
    var regex = new RegExp(expression)
    var t = scripts[i].src
    if (t.match(regex)) {        
        const url = new URL(t)
        if(domains.includes(url.hostname)){
            console.log(url.hostname)
        }else{
            alert(url.hostname)
        }
    }
}
```